# How to get all failures at once in ant migration tool?

Tags: deployment, ant

does any know how to get all failures at once in ant migration tool when deploying? it gives a subset of failures each time when you try to deploy.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the command is normally `ant deployToSalesforce`, you can pipe the output to a file and then read it there with `ant deployToSalesforce 1>stdout.txt 2>stderr.txt`.

`1>` pipes the first channel which is the normal output.

`2>` pipes the second channel which is the error output.

Comment: its not about reading. its about how to get all the failures in one shot then in multiple iterations. say if I am migrating reporttypes and it throws some failures say 50 failures. once I fix these 50 and rerun it, it gives me another ~50 failures. this way it takes for ever, could be days. hope that gives you better context.

Comment: @cloudit, this is an inherent attribute with verification; when it hits something it doesn't understand, it could fail to understand everything that follows/depends onn it. For example, if I tried to deploy `clas Foo { Integer bar = 'hello world'; }`, SF deploy could throw an error on the misspelling of `class` and be unable to proceed with parsing the rest.